# MySQL Query based on HOUR

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a query going to see how many users where "active" during a period of time

So lets say table looks like this

`+---------------------+--------+
| start_date          | active |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2014-02-25 19:37:50 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:35:13 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:24:06 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:16:04 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:14:52 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:10:31 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:08:29 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:08:16 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:09:28 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:06:04 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:17:46 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:06:35 |      0 |
| 2014-02-25 19:06:45 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:00:35 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:02:59 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 18:59:12 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 18:56:57 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:00:44 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 19:07:39 |      1 |
| 2014-02-25 18:54:55 |      1 |
+---------------------+--------+`

I want to know what amount of people where online for each hour of the day.

My previous query looked something like this

`SELECT start_date as date, count(active) as active FROM sessions WHERE start_date>'2014-02-25 00:00:00' GROUP BY hour(start_date);`

However that only seems to return how many people where "active" when their respective start_date was in the hour start_date was looking at (if that makes sense), instead of ALL the users active during that hour (irrespective on when their start_date was).

Any advice?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you also have an end_date, are you looking for something like that?

```
SELECT hour_date, 
SUM((hour(start_date)<=hour_date) and (hour(end_date)>=hour_date)) as active 
FROM sessions, 
(SELECT distinct hour(start_date) as hour_date FROM sessions
WHERE start_date>'2014-02-25 00:00:00') hours
WHERE start_date>'2014-02-25 00:00:00'
GROUP BY hour_date;
```

(the better approach is to get the hours values from a separate table - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc6b9/2)

Comment: Thanks, tried that but got an error

mysql> SELECT hour(start_date) as hour_date,  SUM((hour(start_date)<=hour_date) and (hour(end_date)>=hour_date)) as active from sessions WHERE start_date>'2014-02-25 00:00:00'  GROUP BY hour_date;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'hour_date' in 'field list'

Comment: ah yes, using alias in group_by won't work. changed the answer

Comment: Thanks, however still the same error

mysql> SELECT hour(start_date) as hour_date,  SUM((hour(start_date)<=hour_date) and (hour(end_date)>=hour_date)) as active  FROM sessions WHERE start_date>'2014-02-25 00:00:00' GROUP BY hour(start_date);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'hour_date' in 'field list'

Comment: yep, sorry feel slow by the evening. checked the variant above, seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02212/2

Comment: Regarding the hours, it's quicker (and better) to generate them separately of course: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc6b9/2